# Contar elementos según condición con datos agrupados en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

A ver si me explico, pues es una duda compleja de explicar:

Tengo las siguientes tablas en una base de datos MariaDB (MySQL) en un servidor GNU/Linux:

```
tagente(*id_agente,nombre,direccion,alias,ultimo_contacto)
tevento(*id_evento,id_agente,timestamp,data)
tagent_custom_data(*id_agent,description)
```

[1] La tabla `tevento` almacena por cada agente una serie de datos (0 o 1). De esta tabla necesito obtener el último valor de cada agente (esto me dirá el estado del último evento suyo, si es 0 o 1). Esto lo puedo ver con una query similar a `select e.data from tevento e where e.id_agente = "ID_AGENTE" order by e.timestamp desc limit 1`.

La tabla `tagent_custom_data` almacena un valor concreto por cada agente. Éste se usa para agruparlos en la columna `description`.

Mi objetivo es lograr obtener los siguientes resultados mediante una query: planta (agrupación de `tagent_custom_data.description`), número de agentes agrupados por esa planta y número de agentes con último estado 0 (ver [1]).

Sólo me falta el último valor, la obtención de la cuenta de agentes "negativos" (con último estado de evento 0), que corresponde a la columna `errors`, de momento a null.

```
select cd.description as planta, 
count(*) as total,
null as errors
from tagent_custom_data cd 
group by cd.description;

+--------+-------+--------+
| planta | total | errors |
+--------+-------+--------+
| 309    |     3 |   NULL |
| 346    |     3 |   NULL |
| 351    |     1 |   NULL |
+--------+-------+--------+
```

¿Cómo podría combinarlo, para que me devuelva el valor deseado? Debería devolver algo similar a:

```
+--------+-------+--------+
| planta | total | errors |
+--------+-------+--------+
| 309    |     3 |       2| <-- De los 3 agentes de la planta 309, 2 están a 0
| 346    |     3 |       0| <-- De los 3 agentes de la planta 346, todos están a 1
| 351    |     1 |       1| <-- De los 3 agentes de la planta 351, 1 está a 0
+--------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente esto lo logré anidando queries has obtener el resultado deseado:

```sql
select cd.description as planta, count(*) as total,
(
    select ifnull(
        sum(
            (
                select if (e.data = 0, 1, 0)
                from tevento e
                where e.id_agente = cdy.id_agent
                order by e.timestamp desc
                limit 1
            )
        ), 9999
    ) as errors
    from tagent_custom_data cdy
    where cdy.id_field = cd.id_field and cdy.description = cd.description
) as errors
from tagent_custom_data cd 
where cd.id_field = 6 group by cd.description;


+--------+-------+--------+
| planta | total | errors |
+--------+-------+--------+
| 309    |     3 | 9999   |
| 346    |     3 | 2      |
| 351    |     1 | 0      |
+--------+-------+--------+
```

Lioso pero efectivo.